# Rails console can't find records via class method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-console

I'm totally confused. I'm learning Rails 4 and this returns user records as expected:

```
irb(main):002:0> User.all
```

But *this* returns `nil`

```
irb(main):004:0> User.authenticate('asdfdsf', 'asdfdas')
```

Here's the class method in the model:

```
def self.authenticate( email, password )
    user = User.all #( email: email )
    puts user
    # if user && (user.hashed_password == User.hash_with_salt( password, user.salt ) )
    #   return user
    # else
    #   return false
    # end
end
```

Am I missing something? Shouldn't these both return the same thing? Why can't I return a user object with .find() or .where() from inside a class method?

**Update:**
Here's the schema of my users table:

```
  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "first_name"
    t.string   "last_name"
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "hashed_password"
    t.string   "salt"
  end
```

Comment: *what* can be done with `relaod!`?

Comment: nevermind. :) I posted my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It would if there wasn't `puts user` line. `puts` call returns `nil` and it's returned from whole method as a last evaluated value.

Comment: Thanks. I'm returning the object now. But I'm confused because when I try to call one of it's methods... `u = User.authenticate.first; u.hashed_password` , I get an undefined method error: `undefined method 'hashed_password'`

Comment: @Emerson did you run your migration? What is your db schema?

Comment: I added it to the question. I notice there's no index. Does that matter?

Comment: @Emerson whad does `User.new.hashed_password` return?

Comment: If I do `u = User.find(1)` I get a user object back with a long string in place for the `salt: ` but when I immediately afterwards do `u.salt` I get `nil`

Comment: I figured it out. I had accidentally redeclared `attr_accessor :hashed_password` and it was creating weirdness.